# Выборка значений по типу с максимальным значением

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица

| Тип | Подтип | Количество |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Т1 | ПТ1 | 3 |
| Т1 | ПТ2 | 2 |
| Т2 | ПТ11 | 3 |
| Т2 | ПТ12 | 5 |

Нужно из нее выбрать названия подтипов для каждого типа с наибольшим количеством
то есть должно получится

| Подтип |
| --- |
| ПТ1 |
| ПТ12 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.Подтип 
from (
  select 
    Подтип, 
    rank() over (partition by Тип order by Количество desc) rn 
  from Table) a 
where a.rn=1
```

Это если при совпадении количества нужно вывести все подтипы с максимальным количеством.

Если какой-то один - то используем `row_number` вместо `rank`. Но какая конкретно запись будет первой - неизвестно без дополнительной сортировки в конструкции `over`

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: можно еще через группировку или джойном